# Cannot get UIImage to show in a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, uicollectionview

I'm unable to set an image in a `UICollectionViewCell`, the `UILabel` however, works fine. Here's the relevant code:

```
// CatagoryViewCell.m
#import "CatagoryViewCell.h"

@implementation CatagoryViewCell
@synthesize nameLabel;

- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    [catagoryCellImage setImage:image];
}

@end

// ViewController.m
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"canon.jpg"];
[cell setImage:image];

return cell;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try  catagoryCellImage.image=image; instead [catagoryCellImage setImage:image];

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code,

```
//cell.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface detail : UITableViewCell 
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *check;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *img;
@end


// cell.m

#import "cell.h"

@implementation detail

@synthesize option, img;



 // ViewController.m

    cell.img.image= [UIImage imageNamed:@"canon.jpg"];

    return cell;
```

Comment: Doesn't work either, thanks though. It's a UICollectionViewCell, not a UITableViewCell. Could that make a difference?

Comment: the point is, you should add as subview UIImageView to your UICollectionViewCell subclass' -contentView property. Maybe you are forgetting to add your UIImageView as a subview?

Comment: @art-divin yeah, I haven't added it as a subview, I'll try that. Thank you.